# String manipulation in Pandas Series

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a variable "Age" with varying measures for age stored as a string. Example:

```
Age = ("3 weeks" , "2 years" , "1 day", "4 weeks")
```

I am interested in using the time measure `(weeks, years, day)` to convert the variable to an integer expressing the number in the string as a fraction of a year. In other words, I want to convert 3 weeks into the equivalent of 3/52 in int form.

Any suggestions on how I can do this in pandas? Appreciate any advice that is forthcoming.

M

Comment: Could you give an example of an input and desired output?

Comment: I think the desired solution is clear in my original question. What I'd like is for my pandas series object to go from being a string that says "x weeks" to an int  that is equal to x/52 or "x days" to become an int that is equal to x/365. Both being a fraction of a year.

Comment: Solved the problem with some help from you all with these lines:                                 time = {"year" : 1, "years": 1, "days": 365, "day": 365, "month":12, "months": 12, "week": 52, "weeks": 52}

num = X_train['AgeuponOutcome'].str.split().str[0].astype(float)
measure = X_train['AgeuponOutcome'].str.split().str[1].replace(time.keys(), time.values())

X_train['OutcomeAge'] = num/measure

Answer (score 3):

Using [`parsedatetime`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsedatetime/),

```
import datetime as DT
import pandas as pd
import parsedatetime as pdt

today = DT.date.today()
def parse(x, p=pdt.Calendar()):
    return DT.datetime(*p.parse(x, today.timetuple())[0][:6])

age = ("3 weeks" , "2 years" , "1 day", "4 weeks")
s = pd.Series(age)
s = s.map(parse) - today
s = s / pd.Timedelta(1, unit='Y')
print(s)
```

yields

```
0    0.057496
1    1.998672
2    0.002738
3    0.076661
dtype: float64
```

Comment: OP wants it converted to an int

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
d = {"weeks":52,"years":1,"day":365}
[float(i.split(" ")[0])/d[i.split(" ")[1]] for i in Age]
```

Note that this assumes that all your data is split by a whitespace, and you only have "day" in the data set - if you have instances of "days" you'd have to add that to the dict.

Comment: +1 for cleanest, most flexible solution.  I do note however that OP asked for a solution for pandas, though didn't mention exactly the desired output.

Comment: I get an error saying " 'set' object is not subscriptable" when attempting your solution. I think it is localized to the denominator of your proposed solution. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Have you tried the above code for the `Age` tuple defined in your original question? Don't see where a set would come from here, unless your actual `Age` variable contains one!

Comment: My bad. I enclosed the values in the dict with a ". I adjusted that so my code matches yours but now I get a AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'. I will see if I can figure this out. But if you have advice, it is appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: These are the first 5 values in the series...to give you a better sense: 0     1 year
1     1 year
2    2 years
3    3 weeks
4    2 years

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want, I think, using Python lists:

```
#function to convert each string to fraction in years    
def word2time(strVal):
   num,word = strVal.split()
   num = int(num)
   if word == 'weeks' or word == 'week':
      return float(num)/52
   elif word == 'days' or word == 'day':
      return float(num)/365
   elif word == 'years' or word == 'year':
      return num

#demonstration on the input you provided   
Age = ['3 weeks', '2 years', '1 day', '4 weeks']

ageInYrs = []
for strVal in Age:
   ageInYrs.append(word2time(strVal))

print ageInYrs
```